# Couple questions about parsing xml

Tags: php, xml

Okay I really don't understand this concept but I don't want to use a widget to stay away from their advertisements.

So I'm trying to make like 10 national results from fox news for a clients radio station website. I just want a link so I need to get the title and link from the feed.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest");
print_r($xml);

?>
```

That code prints this

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2.0 ) [channel] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => FOXNews.com [link] => http://www.foxnews.com/ [description] => 
FOX News Channel - We Report. You Decide. [copyright] => Copyright 2013 FOX News Channel 
[managingEditor] => foxnewsonline@foxnews.com [language] => en-us [lastBuildDate] => Sun, 01 
December 2013 10:08:27 EST [webMaster] => foxnewsonline@foxnews.com [image] => SimpleXMLElement 
Object ( [url] => http://www.foxnews.com/images/headers/fnc_logo.gif [title] => FOXNews.com Live 
Bookmark [link] => http://www.foxnews.com/ ) [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [link] => http://www.foxnews.com/us/2013/12/01/metro-north-
passenger-train-derails-in-nyc-leaving-some-cars-in-water/ [author] => foxnewsonline@foxnews.com 
[description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [pubDate] => Sun, 01 Dec 2013 09:49:42 EST ) [1] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [link] => 
http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/12/01/obamacare-website-re-do-deadline-set-for-saturday/ 
[author] => foxnewsonline@foxnews.com [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [pubDate] => Sun, 
01 Dec 2013 09:49:42 EST )
```

I shortened it so it's easier to read. The full one is on patriotvoice.net. In the above code I noticed the title is a SimpleXMLElement Object and I've tried to print it out using `print_r($xml->item[0]->title);` but it doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong so I can have 10 `<a href="$link">$title</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$link = $xml->channel->item[37]->link;
$title = $xml->channel->item[37]->title;
print "<a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! I'll just modify the statements to make 10 of them and it'll be ugly but it will work

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast leaf-values into **String**.

```
var_dump((string)$xml->channel->item[0]->title);
```

Without casting, they only represent empty SimpleXMLElements.

Comment: that returns `string(0) ""`